# How to implement upvote system without user authentication with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app where an upvote system will be implemented with firebase, but this app doesn't have user logi0/sign up nor I wish to add one. I've read the [documentation on `transaction()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions)  to figure out how to implement an upvote system in my app, but I can't figure out how to use it without user login? I have a Post class which is similar to what is given in the Firebase documentation

```
public class _Post {
public String uid;
public String timeStamp;
public String author;
public String body;
public int starCount = 0;
public Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

public _Post() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
}

public _Post(String uid, String author, String body, String timeStamp) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.author = author;
    this.body = body;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("uid", uid);
    result.put("author", author);
    result.put("body", body);
    result.put("starCount", starCount);
    result.put("stars", stars);
    result.put("time", timeStamp);
    return result;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public int getStarCount() {
    return starCount;
}

public Map<String, Boolean> getStars() {
    return stars;
}
```

}

Here's my method to upvote, that I also took from the firebase docs/guide

```
private void onStarClicked(String postId, final String uid) {
    DatabaseReference postRef = mDatabaseRef.child("north_america").child("posts").child(postId);
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            _Post p = mutableData.getValue(_Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(uid)) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(uid);
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(uid, true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

Another problem I'm having is how will my firebase Posts node look like? 
Maybe like this? (My app talks about upcoming movies)

```
-- north_america
--- posts
---- movie_id
```

And `movie_id` would be something like this?

1123 is the movie's id in this example

```
"1123": {
    "uid": "user_2",
    "title": "I am legend"
    "likes": 0
}
```

And what will a Post object in the Posts node contain?

Comment: If your users don't sign in, what is the meaning of the `String uid` that you pass into the `Post`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if there's no user, this means a device can increment multiple times no? I only want a device to increment once

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to identify a device/session securely without requiring the user to provide credentials. For that purpose Firebase provides anonymous authentication. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth. I updated my answer with some more info about this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to identify a device/session securely without requiring the user to provide credentials, you can use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This allows you to create a "session" for the user on the current device by simply calling:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
```

This identifies the user on the client and (more importantly) on the server, so that you can ensure each user can only vote once.

If you don't care about limiting the number of votes per user, and simply want to increment the `likes` of a movie transactionally, do something like this on each click:

```
private void onStarClicked(String postId, final String uid) {
    DatabaseReference postRef = mDatabaseRef.child("north_america/posts").child(postId).child("likes");
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Long value = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
            if (value == null) value = new Long(0);
            mutableData.setValue(value + 1);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

The code simply performs a transaction on the `likes` property, incrementing its value.

Comment: Thank you so much!! And do you have an idea how will a Post object look like? Is the one I provided at the end of my question any good?

Comment: How can I accomplish this if a user is signed in?

Comment: The code in your question does precisely that: it takes the UID and records a vote for that user.